# Pandas to_hdf and import to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, pandas, import, hdf5

I encountered a weird problem, and can't find what I'm doing wrong:

In Python, I have a simple matrix as pandas dataframe (6000 x 1500 matrix). As I want to read this into Matlab I'm saving the dataframe as HDF5 as follows:

```
 df.to_hdf("output.hdf","mytable", format="table")
```

Saving works fine, and reading back to Python with pd.read_hdf, also works fine. But when I try to import the same file into Matlab as follows:

```
 data = h5read('output.hdf','/mytable')
```

I just get an error:

```
 H5Dopen2    not a dataset
```

Somewhere I read to leave a space in the dataset name ('/ mytable') but that just returns an "object doesn't exist" error.

Any hints on what might go wrong here is highly appreciated.

Comment: Any issues in saving to CSV and then reading it through `readtable()` in matlab?

Comment: Or saving it as a `.mat`

Comment: Yes. Tried that as well, but that takes way too long to load.

Answer (score 2):

Playing around with h5info in Matlab, I figured out that in Matlab I need to explicitly specify "table" in the dataset:

```
   data = h5read('output.hdf','/mytable/table')
```

At least this imports the HDF5. Strange though that I have not seen this mentioned anywhere.

However, now it seems that some rows are not imported correctly, which I need to further investigate.